# error Unexpected side effect in "allOptions" computed property vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, lodash

I trying to just find the index of the answer in my array in the `computed`  region of Vue js but I am getting an error that some Unexpected side effect has occured

code :-

```
<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  name: "QuestionBottom",
  props: {
    currentQuestion: Object,
    nextQuestion: Function,
    increment: Function,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: null,
      correctIndex: null,
    };
  },
  // watch changes to the props
  watch: {
    currentQuestion() {
      this.selectedIndex = null;
    },
  },

  computed: {
    allOptions() {
      let allOptions = [
        ...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers,
        this.currentQuestion.correct_answer,
      ];

      console.log("array that is not shuffled is ", allOptions);
      allOptions = _.shuffle(allOptions);
      console.log("shuffled array is", allOptions);
      console.log("Corect ans is ", this.currentQuestion.correct_answer);

      // here is the error occurring
      this.correctIndex = allOptions.indexOf(
        this.currentQuestion.correct_answer
      );
      return allOptions;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    selectedAns(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      console.log("Selected answer index", this.selectedIndex);
    },
    submitAnswer() {
      let isCorrect = false;
      if (this.selectedIndex === this.correctIndex) {
        isCorrect = true;
      }

      this.increment(isCorrect);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    // console.log(this.currentQuestion);
  },
};
</script>
```

I am fairly new in Vue.js. I don't know what is the reason that this unexpected behavior is occurring in the computed region to my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue does not like changing a data variable (`correctIndex`) inside a computed property (`allOptions`). I would put that part into a watched method. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```
computed: {
    allOptions() {
      let allOptions = [
        ...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers,
        this.currentQuestion.correct_answer,
      ];

      console.log("array that is not shuffled is ", allOptions);
      allOptions = _.shuffle(allOptions);
      console.log("shuffled array is", allOptions);
      console.log("Corect ans is ", this.currentQuestion.correct_answer);
      return allOptions;
    },

    watch: {
        allOptions() {
            this.correctIndex = allOptions.indexOf(this.currentQuestion.correct_answer);
        }
    }
```

That way `allOptions` stays computed, and will do just it's thing (and nothing more) - but is watched. Everytime it changes, `correctIndex` will be updated accordingly.